# How to read strings as integers when reading from a file in python

Tags: python

I have the following line of code reading in a specific part of a text file. The problem is these are numbers not strings so I want to convert them to ints and read them into a list of some sort.

A sample of the data from the text file is as follows:

However this is not wholly representative I have uploaded the full set of data here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=08754130146692169643 as a text file.

*NSET, NSET=Nodes_Pushed_Back_IB

`99915527,  99915529,  99915530,  99915532,  99915533,  99915548,  99915549,  99915550,
  99915551,  99915552,  99915553,  99915554,  99915555,  99915556,  99915557,  99915558,
  99915562,  99915563,  99915564,  99915656,  99915657,  99915658,  99915659,  99915660,
  99915661,  99915662,  99915663,  99915664,  99915665,  99915666,  99915667,  99915668,
  99915669,  99915670,  99915885,  99915886,  99915887,  99915888,  99915889,  99915890,
  99915891,  99915892,  99915893,  99915894,  99915895,  99915896,  99915897,  99915898,
  99915899,  99915900,  99916042,  99916043,  99916044,  99916045,  99916046,  99916047,
  99916048,  99916049,  99916050`

*NSET, NSET=Nodes_Pushed_Back_OB

Any help would be much appreciated.

Hi I am still stuck with this issue any more suggestions? Latest code and error message is as below Thanks!

```
 import tkinter as tk
 from tkinter import filedialog
 file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
 print(file_path)
 data =  []
 data2 = []
 data3 = []
 flag= False
 with open(file_path,'r') as f:
     for line in f:
         if line.strip().startswith('*NSET, NSET=Nodes_Pushed_Back_IB'):
             flag= True
         elif line.strip().endswith('*NSET, NSET=Nodes_Pushed_Back_OB'):
             flag= False    #loop stops when condition is false i.e if false do nothing
         elif flag:          # as long as flag is true append
             data.append([int(x) for x in line.strip().split(',')]) 

 result is the following error:

 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Instead of reading these as strings I would like each to be a number in a list, i.e `[98932850 98932852 98932853 98932855 98932856 98932871 98932872 98932873]`

Comment: From your code, does any line start with '*NSET, NSET=Nodes_Pushed_Back_IB'? we need to see a perfect representation of the line. And then you need to split valid lines

Comment: Hi thanks AAA Yes I have edited the sample data in my original question above to include where '*NSET, NSET=Nodes_Pushed_Back_IB' is. The data set is quite large so have not included all the data but the above is representative.  Should I then have: data.append(strip().split(","))? How then to convert the values to int. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases I use regular expressions together with string methods. I would solve this problem like so:

```
import re 
with open(filepath) as f:
    txt = f.read()

g = re.search(r'NSET=Nodes_Pushed_Back_IB(.*)', txt, re.S)
snums = g.group(1).replace(',', ' ').split()
numbers = [int(num) for num in snums]
```

I read the entire text into `txt`.
Next I use a regular expression and use the last portion of your header in the text as an anchor, and capture with capturing parenthesis all the rest (the re.S flag means that a dot should capture also newlines). I access all the nubers as one unit of text via `g.group(1)`.

Next. I remove all the commas (actually replace them with spaces) because on the resulting text I use `split()` which is an excellent function to use on text items that are separated with spaces - it doesn't matter the amount of spaces, it just splits it as you would intent.

The rest is just converting the text to numbers using a list comprehension.

Comment: Hi thanks i the following error when trying this: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '*NSET'

Comment: Make sure you copy the program exactly as it is. The regular expression gets rid of the header.

Answer (score 1):

Your line contains more than one number, and some separating characters. You could parse that format by judicious application of `split` and perhaps `strip`, or you could minimize string handling by having `re` extract specifically the fields you care about:

```
ints = list(map(int, re.findall(r'-?\d+', line)))
```

This regular expression will find each group of digits, optionally prefixed by a minus sign, and then `map` will apply `int` to each such group found.

Answer (score 1):

Using a sample of your string:

```
strings = '  98932850,  98932852,  98932853,  98932855,  98932856,  98932871,  98932872,  98932873,\n'
```

I'd just split the string, strip the commas, and return a list of numbers:

```
numbers = [ int(s.strip(',')) for s in strings.split() ]
```

Based on your comment and regarding the larger context of your code. I'd suggest a few things:

```
from itertools import groupby
number_groups = []
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for k, g in groupby(f, key=lambda x: x.startswith('*NSET')):
        if k:
            pass
        else:
            number_groups += list(filter('\n'.__ne__, list(g)))  #remove newlines in list

data = []
for group in number_groups:
    for str_num in group.strip('\n').split(','):
        data.append(int(str_num))
```

Comment: Hi I tried this at the end of my existing line of code but get the following error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: If you have a list of strings, then it is even simpler: just remove the split() function.

Comment: Thanks for the help I am however hoping to adapt the code I currently have in combination with your first suggestion. I have edited the code in my original question. I do not understand why this does not work.

Comment: @Jay My guess is that you have list of strings. And, you're trying to split the list instead of the string. I included in my example two vars, `group` and `str_num`, to highlight that issue.

Comment: Hi thanks however I still can not get this to work even with your suggested second code. I have uploaded the full set of data as a text file in the original post as II realized the formatting is slightly different. I tried to replace `data.append(line.strip())` with `data.append([int(x) for x in line.replace(" ", "").split(',')])`. However this still does not work. The split function seems to work on this however it still throws up an error in regards to  `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n' ` So I can not seem to remove the space. That I think comes in when I split.

Comment: @Jay That error is about newlines (\n). Now that I have you're data, I see that you'll also have to clean those up as well, so I've update my snippet to reflect that: see the `strip('\n')`chained before the split function.  BTW, I've successfully tested my code against the data you uploaded.

Comment: Hi Gregory if I use the above amended code I get `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`. It seems at the end of each line there is still a ` ''] ` which I do not know how to get rid of. I have copied exactly what you wrote but changed the `data.txt'` to `file_path`.  Thanks